# How to login in LinkedIn automatically from asp.net application?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, linkedin-api

I have dummy username and pasword to enter in linkedin. From an asp.net application, when the button is clicked i need to login automatically used the username and password in linkedIn.

How to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A direct (server to server) login is not possible. It wouldn't be nice to ask your users for their LinkedIn account and password.

You can implement OAuth between you (consumer) and LinkedIn (provider) and let the user log directly to LinkedIn. More info about this on:

http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1008

Answer (score 1):

By loading your destination URl into a Web-browser element and being redirected, .net would allow handling of the body html and auto click of the login for this.

Alternatively you can pass the header value with the request that would pass through auth - should last 2 days a time I believe.